# Document Libraries in Sharepoint 2010/2013

Tags: document-library

I have set up two farms (1 in 2010 and 1 in 2013). I have not done too much with either environment yet but a question came up and I don't know if Sharepoint can even do this.

In this scenario, we have an "intranet" site that comes up when a user first logs in.  On this first page are links to the other departments that are sub-sites of this main site (i.e. HR, ITS, etc.).  Also on this first page is a document library that has documents that are stored in the other sub-sites but would be useful to show on the first page.  So instead of going to the HR department's sub-site for a time sheet, this document would be here as well.  The document lives in the HR site but there is a reference to it here as well as other documents from other sites.

So with this scenario, is there a web part that can be used to achieve this?  It could be done with multiple web parts.  I do know a little about Document Libraries but I don't know of any way to do a shared document library that matches my scenario.  We are looking at doing an employee portal and would like to use Sharepoint but one of the requirements is something similar to what I described.  I'm just trying to get some indication whether I should start looking deeper at certain web parts (we like to stay as close to vanilla as possible) or if I need to work on getting some custom web parts going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show list views from sub sites on a top level site. To do that you need to do this:

- open the sub site in SharePoint Designer
- open the library and open any one of the list views
- select the LVWP and on the ribbon select the Web Part ribbon
- use the command to Save the web part "To File"
- answer the dialog whether to always show list data from the current list with "Yes".
- close SharePoint Designer without saving any changes
- open the top level site in the browser and upload the web part
- you can now configure the web part and edit the view.

This has been described in more detail by Laura Rogers [on the 911 blog](http://www.sharepoint911.com/blogs/laura/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=daba3a3b-c338-41d8-bf52-cd897d000cf3&ID=76&Web=dbb90e85-b54c-49f4-8e97-6d8258116ca0)
It works in 2010. Have not tried in 2013.

This technique can bubble up list views from sub sites to the top level site, but it will not work to display a top level list view on a sub site.

Comment: Yes this did work for me.  Thank you.  I am attempting this same thing in our 2013 environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharePoint Search Web Parts to display documents from HR or other departments on the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Create a "Quick Reference" library, add on the landing page as a web part.

Send copies of documents (with the "prompt author to update copies" option checked) you want to appear on the landing page to Quick Reference library.

Ta-da, OOTB solution.